# Index of current item in mvc display template

Tags: controls, asp.net-mvc-3, indexing, ienumerable

I have an mvc page with a displaytemplate.
How do I get the index of the current item being rendered in the displaytemplate.
it produces correct bindable results in the name attributes.

```
<input name="xxx[0].FirstName"/>
<input name="xxx[1].FirstName"/>
```

I want that index value in the display template. Is it in the ViewContext somewhere?

@* page.cshtml *@
@model ...@* property Contacts is IEnumerable *@

```
<table id="contacts" class="editable">
    <thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Contact Details</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Contacts)
    </tbody>
```

in the display template we have

```
@* contact.cshtml *@
@model ...@* This is the T of the IEnumerable<T> *@

<tr>
   @* I NEED THE INDEX OF THE CURRENT ITERATION HERE *@
   <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName)</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am afraid there is no easy way to get the index. It's buried inside the internal `System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultDisplayTemplates.CollectionTemplate` method and not exposed. What you could use is the field prefix:

```
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

Another possibility is replace `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Contacts)` with:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Contacts.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Contacts[i], new { Index = i })
}
```

and then inside the template `@ViewBag.Index` should give you the current index but I must admit it's kinda ugly.

Comment: Thanks, I will parse it out of the prefix.

Comment: @Jim, be careful with the parsing because you could have deep levels like `Contacts[5].Addresses[7]`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will bear that in mind. Ten years ago I would have spent a few weeks writing the most flexible and elegant multi level parser. Today I will take the last matching number and have at it!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, thanks for directing me to `@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix` - I had been looking for a solution to this for several hours. I agree with @Jim's sentiment, a simple non-elegant solution will work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on why you need the index, there may be an easier way.

I was doing something similar and wanted the index just so I could easily number the list of items such as:

1. First items in List
2. Second item in List
   etc.

The maybe obvious solution was to render my display template as a List Item within an Order List, and let the browser handle the display of the index. I was originally doing this in a table and needed the index to display in the table, but using a ordered list makes it much easier.

So my parent view had the following:

```
<ol>
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items)
</ol>
```

And my template wrote on the items in an list item using divs - note you could use floating divs, or better yet display: inline-style to get a table like effect

```
<li>
    <div class="class1">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ItemType)</div>
    ...
</li>
```

And the css:

```
.class1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extending @DarinDimitrov's answer, I wanted to submit a complete solution:

Extention:

```
namespace ApplicationName.Helpers
{
    public static class RazorHtmlHelpers
    {
        public static Int32 GetTemplateIndex(this TemplateInfo template)
        {
            var index = 0;

            var match = Regex.Match(template.HtmlFieldPrefix, @"\d");
            Int32.TryParse(match.Value, out index);

            return index;
        }
    }
}
```

Parent View Markup:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Items)
```

Template Markup:

```
@using ApplicationName.Helpers
@model ApplicationName.Models.ModelName

<span>Item @ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetTemplateIndex()</span>
```