# How to alternate row style without javascript for DisplayFor/EditorFor bound to a list of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I pass the index of the current element to the View for DisplayFor/EditorFor so that I can decide if the row should show the alternate style or not?

My main view looks like this:

```
<table>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MyListOfItems)
</table>
```

The view used for the EditorFor looks like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IdOfTheItem)
<tr class="shouldBeChangedDependingOnRowEvenOrNot">
<td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MarkForBatchEdit)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NameOfThisItem)</td>
<td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StateOfThisItem)</td>
</tr>
```

Well I am aware of this similar question and the suggested solution: [alternating row color MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593477/alternating-row-color-mvc)

But I can't apply them to this case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: actually I just found this (which is quite the similar question):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814308/index-of-current-item-in-mvc-display-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EditorFor` is overloaded to take an [additionalViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406462%28VS.100%29.aspx) parameter, so you could pass the index in the [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505255%28VS.100%29.aspx), which is a collection of key/value pairs.

```
@Html.EditorFor( model => model.MyListOfItems , new { CurrentIndex = SomeNumber } )
```

In your view you would get the value using `ViewData["CurrentIndex"]`.

Also, instead of passing the element index, why not do the calculation in your controller and pass whether you have an even or odd row in your `ViewData`.

```
bool isEvenRow = ((CurrentElementIndex % 2) == 0);
ViewData["isEvenRow"] = isEvenRow;
```

Then you will just toggle your CSS in the view based on whether the value is true or false.

Comment: I work with Models for everything: so I would add the Property IsEvenRow to MyItem, but still I am not sure where I could get this CurrentElementIndex from, without having to do an additional foreach loop over all the elements.

Comment: oh, actually I can use index in my controller that uses LINQ.

Comment: well actually I extended my View in the back with a Property that gets filled when the List is querried. Thank you for your help.